# Date-countdown with local notifications based on how many weeks left

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, uilocalnotification, uidatepicker

So I'm developing a function in my app that lets the user choose a date, let,s say 15. April to make it clear. Then when it's four weeks left, 18th of April, a local notification pops up and says: "Four weeks left!". When it's two weeks left, 1st of April, it says: Only two weeks left. Same for a week left, 8th of April, saying: "Only one week now!". Then when it's three days left, 12th of April, it says: "It's getting closer, only three days now!". And at last, the day, 15th of april, saying: "It's your day today!".

So, maybe a bit long explanation there, But, now you know the issue. Does anyone have a sample code with a short explanation for me to understand it or something? Like a base-code for me to further develop. Or maybe a link to a tutorial, cause I can't seem to find anything.

Hope someone have time to answer this question, I  will be truly gratefull!

Best regards,
Øyvind Larsen Runestad.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `endDate` in `NSDate, and find the difference between`currentDate`and`endDate`.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *endDate = ...;
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:startDate  toDate:endDate  options:0];

int months = [comps month];
int days = [comps day];
```

After this make if-else statements and based on your condition show an alert or send a notification to other class/object.

Comment: So, to make this clear since I'm not good at this. 1. I put in a calender picker and code this correctly, then I put in your above code in ViewController.m, then I code five UILocalnotifications where I get the info from where? Sorry for all the questions.